# can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.,

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Hb1.jpg)

I cannot get the value saved in my email and password variables

Answer (score 0):

Put the ! Character at the end of ["email"] and ["password"] and learn about null safety from the flutter docs

Answer (score 0):

Because String is a non-nullable type, then the variable must be guaranteed to receive some non-null value.

```
String? a;
String b = a ?? '';
```